# customize the line chart in flex

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I am working on line chart in flex. I have to show the tooltip data on the datapoint itself. Normally the data point value is displayed on a rectangular area when we mouse over on the data-point. But I have a checkbox just below the chart. When I check on it, all the datapoints of the graph should display the value on data-point on the graph. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In your mx:LineChart control set the showAllDataTips value to true/false according to your checkbox.

Comment: I didnot mean the datatips here. I mean the datapoint..the circle which appears when we mouse over it. At that point I want to show the value. Data tip is that rectangular box which appears when we mouse over on the datapoint of the line-graph

Answer (score 0):

After doing a few research I found the answer. My goal was to draw something on the datapoint itself. I found this link useful [<strike>Drawing on chart controls</strike>](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_eventsandeffects_13.html#298038) EDIT : [new link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7c44.html)
Going through this link helped me a lot.